# Kafka adding new consumers does not rebalance the load

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a topic with 3 partitions on 2 brokers. (Kafka version: 0.8.1)

Messages are bulk added using different user guid (like this: FC42B34DD7658503E040970A2C437358) as partition key. (about 10k messages)

While loading the messages, I have one running consumer (consumer1), it starts handling the messages fine.
Then I started another consumer (consumer2) with same consumer group id.

What I noticed is that, consumer1 stops handling the messages, and consumer2 starts handling all the messages.

When I stop consumer2, then consumer1 took over and resumes message processing.

I was expecting both consumers should distribute the load.

Any clue where could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Is it because on the client I configured stream=3?

Comment: even after I changed stream to 1, still after a while ~20 min, one consumer stops processing, i.e. only one consumer processes the messages at a time

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what happens in your consumers exactly without some inspections on your Zookeeper cluster, but I can suspect one possible scenario that your producers may not evenly distribute messages to the partitions.

[image]

A partition is owned by a single consumer in a single consumer group. The owner consumer is called a `partition owner`, and all messages come in to a partition is exclusively consumed by its partition owner. (For more information, refer to [Consumers](http://kafka.apache.org/081/documentation.html#intro_consumers) in Kafka 0.8.1 documentation.

Let us say there are three partitions A, B, C and two consumers 1 and 2, and the producers only send messages to the partition B.

When there is only consumer 1, all messages of the partition B are consumed by the consumer 1.

When you introduce consumer 2, now the partition B is assigned to the consumer 2 by a consumer rebalancing algorithm. Since your producers send messages only to the partition B, now the consumer 2 becomes the only consumer that consumes messages.

After you stop the consumer 2, the partition B is assigned to the consumer 1 again, and all messages are consumed by the consumer 1.

The above scenario is what I can think of. Check whether your producer implementation has a distribution problem.

Comment: I used the default partitioning strategy with user guid (FC42B34DD7658503E040970A2C437358) as partition key. For this kind of partition key, any other better partition algorithm for a more balanced distribution? Thanks.

Comment: @heyu The default partitioner will send messages to the same partition if there keys are the same. If the keys are always the same even in the production, I recommend not to use message keys. If you send messages without keys, Kafka uses a random partitioner (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-Whyisdatanotevenlydistributedamongpartitionswhenapartitioningkeyisnotspecified?). If you want something else, try to use a round-robin partitioner (http://qnalist.com/questions/4651371/kafka-producer-behavior).

Comment: @heyu Be aware that the random partitioner is not randomly sending messages to partitions. It chooses a partition and sticks to send messages to the chosen partition for some period time (default 10 mins). For more information, refer to the link I gave you above.

Comment: i'm not using same value as partition key, I just gave one example that user guid will look like that - different user will have different guid. Just wondering with such kind of values, how balance would the random partition distribute values.

Comment: @heyu Here is code for the default partitioner: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.8.2/core/src/main/scala/kafka/producer/DefaultPartitioner.scala

It does a simple mod calculation on the key's hash: `Utils.abs(key.hashCode) % numPartitions`