# Can Kafka consumer group running on different machines receive unique messages?

Tags: java, message-queue, apache-kafka

To avoid redundant messages when consumer crashes and comes back up, I have disabled auto commit of offsets and manually committing them.

Now the question is if same topic is accessed by consumer processes on different machines, will they receive unique messages? Looking at it theoretically, manual committing will result into redundant messages received on different machines.

On my local machine I ran two instances of java consumer subscribing to same topic and they got repeated messages. How to tackle this thing? I am using high level consumer

Answer (score 2):

Since Kafka's message delivery semantic is *at-least-once*, you should implement your own codes to guarantee *exactly-once* semantic in Kafka.

- At most once: Messages may be lost but are never redelivered.
- At least once: Messages are never lost but may be redelivered.
- Exactly once: this is what people actually want, each message is delivered once and only once.

From [4.6 Message Delivery Semantics](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#semantics) in Kafka Documentation:

> So what about exactly once semantics (i.e. the thing you actually want)? The limitation here is not actually a feature of the messaging system but rather the need to co-ordinate the consumer's position with what is actually stored as output. The classic way of achieving this would be to introduce a two-phase commit between the storage for the consumer position and the storage of the consumers output. But this can be handled more simply and generally by simply letting the consumer store its offset in the same place as its output. This is better because many of the output systems a consumer might want to write to will not support a two-phase commit. As an example of this, our Hadoop ETL that populates data in HDFS stores its offsets in HDFS with the data it reads so that it is guaranteed that either data and offsets are both updated or neither is. We follow similar patterns for many other data systems which require these stronger semantics and for which the messages do not have a primary key to allow for deduplication.

There is also a question which has a similar answer in Kafka FAQ: [How do I get exactly-once messaging from Kafka?](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-HowdoIgetexactly-oncemessagingfromKafka?)

Comment: thanks for your answer. Now the actual case is that of a failure. Consumers are manually committing offsets. So when consumer is committing offset it is committing for that entire topic or it's own offsets?. If one consumer has finished processing a message and commits offset and another consumer is still processing another message and fails, then, when that consumer comes back up, will it have lost that unprocessed message?

Comment: e.g c1 => message @ offset 2 and c2 => message @ offset 1. c1 finishes processing his message and commits offset. At that time c2 is still processing his message of offset 1 and before commiting crashes. Now till that time c1 has moved along and is processing message @ offset 3. c2 comes up now. So message of which offset will it receive?

Comment: @Shades88 The scenario you gave me cannot happen. Each partition has its own offset, and each partition is assigned to a consumer. Each partition can only be accessed by the consumer assigned to it. That is, two consumers cannot access the same partition nor the same offset sequence. For for information, refer to my other answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29314029/961314 http://stackoverflow.com/a/29291884/961314

Comment: Ok, my basics weren't clear. Bt now another question. If a consumer is assigned only a specific partition. And I have only one consumer then how come rest of the partitions are used? I mean, so far I have tested with single consumer subscribing to a topic with 3 partitions. And consumer seems to be reading from all partitions

Comment: @Shades88 A partition is assigned to a single consumer, but the single consumer can take in charge of multiple partitions. The relation between them is not one-to-one, consumer-to-partition. it is one-to-many, consumer-to-partitions.

Comment: I performed a test, where in two consumer processes were started. Producer started publishing messages. Mid way through the consumption I made one of the consumers crash. The other resumed consuming. Then before message publishing would end I restarted the crashed consumer. All the messages were being written in a file. After publishing ended, which was 1000 messages, file was showing about 1100 messages. Which means duplicate messages occurred. How to prevent this behaviour?